# how to send background notification to client on chat web app

Tags: firebase, next.js, push-notification, chat, service-worker

i am creating a web based chatting application with `firebase` and `next.js`. which is currently in development.

the problem i am facing is i want to have push notification for every new message received to user when the app in not in foreground. is their any thing to do with service worker?

i thought of using service worker to do so. but i don't know how to write service worker. i have stored user auth token in react context can i use it in service worker ?

i am fetching chats from messages array stored in `firestore doc` of chat between two people.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i don't know how to explain it but simply i want to fetch some data from `firestore` in background and on the basis of that i want to send push notification to user.